# botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed on WIndows

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, boto3

The below code is for getting the regions.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', 'region-name')
print(ec2.describe_regions())
```

On executing this code on my machine, I'm getting this error.

> botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://ec2.region-name.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

I am running this code on Windows 10 machine with **VS code** as my editor. I looked for other answers where they required to install `Install Certificates.command` file. However, looks like it is found on macOS only.

Can someone tell me the reason for this issue as well?

Also, last week got a notification from AWS that they are updating all their AWS FIPS endpoints to TLS 1.2
and hence need to connect to TLS version 1.2 FIPS endpoints. I checked my TLS version [here](https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check). It says I have TLS version 1.2. Is there anything related to this? Because prior to this notification, my script was running perfectly.

Please someone tell the reason for this error and possible correction. Also, correct me if I mentioned something wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 17):

`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate` is because Python `ssl` library can't find certificates on your local machine to verify against.

One way to debug is to see if you have your `ca_bundle` set to something else:

```
python -c "from botocore.session import Session; print(Session().get_config_variable('ca_bundle'))"
```

If it doesn't print anything, then it uses default path. You can check default path by:

```
python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
```

If `ca_bundle` prints something, then it's set by `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable or by `aws configure set default.ca_bundle <some path>` in the past. Also check `~/.aws/config` if you accidentally setting it there (config file location for Windows: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).

`Install Certificates.command` is basically a Python script that you can run yourself https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3 . Save as `install-cert.py` and run it `python install-cert.py`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an edge case, but I was having this issue sending requests to a docker container, and the fix for me was hitting the docker container at `http://localhost:8000` instead of `https://localhost:8000` since the container couldn't receive SSL requests. Hopefully that helps anyone in this particular situation!

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3    

from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning    
from urllib3 import disable_warnings    
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')    
client = session.client('ec2', verify=False)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: As much as I don't endorse code-only answers, this is a valid WORKAROUND and should be used only as a very last resort. As much as possible, do verify your TLS connections people! This snippet disables all the safeties of TLS and host verifications, so you could leave yourself open to MITM attacks. Do not use in production.